# Relation between two functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Fix $x\in \mathcal{X}$ and take the functions
$$
\bar{t}(x)\equiv \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}(\bar{g}(x,y)-\bar{h}(x,y))p(y)
$$
$$
t(x)\equiv \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}(g(x,y)-h(x,y))p(y)
$$
where

- $p(y)\in [0,1]$ for each $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}p(y)=1$
- $\bar{g}, g, \bar{h}, h$ have the same domain $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$
- $\bar{g}(x,y)\in [0,1]$, $\bar{h}(x,y)\in [0,1]$, $g(x,y)\in [0,1]$, $h(x,y)\in [0,1]$ for each $(x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$
- $\bar{g}(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$ and $\bar{h}(x,y)\geq h(x,y)$ for each $(x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$

Consider the intervals
$$
\bar{I}=[\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \bar{t}(x), \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \bar{t}(x)]
$$
$$
I=[\min_{x\in \mathcal{X}} t(x), \max_{x\in \mathcal{X}} t(x)]
$$

Should we expect that $I\subseteq \bar{I}$?

Comment: I don't think so. Consider $\bar{g} = g$ and $\bar{h} = h + 1$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$.